# Excel: Forecasting Value from Table - Error

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to interpolate a value between 2 sets of condition - Temperature and Pressure. The Density value for these are filled in.
Now for a given temperature and pressure, I want to interpolate the Density. I followed advice from other forum post and got half way there. The other half, I get an "#N/A".
Attached is the formula used. Any help in diagnosing error is helpful.

[image: Formula Used]

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should remove -1 from MATCH formulas for MATCH to work.

your formula (at the MATCH) returns an error because the values in the range O10:O14 are not in descending order. see the link for [adittional info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

after this I've got #REF! error. while digging I've noticed that OFFSET height has the value of 0 that is causes this error. if you don't whant height just leave it empty, so I've cleared 0 and got "132.3306" (not error).

So final formula will be like this:

```
=FORECAST.LINEAR(K8,OFFSET(U10:U14,MATCH(K8,O10:O14,1),-1,,2),OFFSET(O10:O14,MATCH(K8,U10:U14,1),-1,,2))
```

You can look at ScreenShot also:

[image: You can look at ScreenShot also]

Comment: Thanks Bes. The height and -1 were the culprit indeed. Thank you very much for the help here. Appreciate it.